# Message: Trying to get property of non-object in php error

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
public function user_login()
{ 
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_category', 'User type', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('defaultReal', 'Security Letter', 'trim|required');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'captcha', 'trim|callback_check_captcha|required' );
    //$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span style="color: red;">', '</span>');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', 'Invalid username / password or login type.');
        $data['image']=$this->_create_captcha();
        redirect('login-type-select','location');
    }
    else{
            $uname = $this->db_helper_model->SecureSql($this->input->post('username',TRUE));


            if($this->rpHash($this->input->post('defaultReal')) == $this->input->post('defaultRealHash')) 
            {
                //$user_type = $this->db_helper_model->SecureSql($this->input->post('user_category'));
                $username = $this->db_helper_model->SecureSql($this->input->post('username',TRUE));
                $password = $this->db_helper_model->SecureSql($this->input->post('password',TRUE));

                /* Validating User Wrong Login Attempt */
                $get_userid_by_username = $this->login_model->get_user_id_by_uname($username);
                $lock_status = '';
                $diff_minutes = '';
                $userid_attempt_check = $get_userid_by_username->userid;
                if(!empty($get_userid_by_username))
                {
                    $get_login_attempt = $this->login_model->get_login_attemp_detail($userid_attempt_check);
                    $lock_status = $get_login_attempt->account_lock_status;
                    $lock_datetime = strtotime($get_login_attempt->last_log_fail_time);
                    $curr_datetime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

                    $interval  = abs($curr_datetime - $lock_datetime);
                    $diff_minutes   = round($interval / 60);
                }
                if(($lock_status == '2') && ($diff_minutes <= 30))
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', 'This Account Has Been Locked For 30 Mins');
                    redirect('login-type-select','location');
                }
                //echo $lock_status;
                //echo $diff_minutes; exit;
                else
                {
                    //$table = $this->input->post('hid_tbl_name');
                    //$hid_user_type = $this->input->post('hid_user_type');
                    $data['login_status'] = $this->login_model->check_username_password($username,$password);
                    //$data['login_status'] = $this->login_model->check_username_password($username,$password,$user_type);
                    if($data['login_status']!=''){
                    $set_user_in_session = array(
                    'user_id'=> $data['login_status']->id,
                    'username'=> $data['login_status']->username,
                    'designation'=> $data['login_status']->designation,
                    'role'=> $data['login_status']->role,
                    'work_role'=> $data['login_status']->work_role,
                    'college_id'=> $data['login_status']->college_id,
                    'first_name'=> $data['login_status']->first_name,
                    'last_name'=> $data['login_status']->last_name,
                    'email'=> $data['login_status']->email,
                    'active_status'=> $data['login_status']->active_status
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($set_user_in_session);

                    /* Clean Attemp Details */
                    $update_login_lock_status = $this->login_model->func_update_login_lock_status($userid_attempt_check);
                    $update_login_attempt = $this->login_model->func_update_login_attempt($userid_attempt_check);

                    $valueofvaliduser=rand(123456789,987654321);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('authentication',$valueofvaliduser);
                    setcookie('validluser',$valueofvaliduser,0,'/','',false,true);

                    $get_user_assigned_page_url = $this->login_model->get_user_assigned_pageurl($data['login_status']->role,$data['login_status']->designation,$data['login_status']->college_id);
                    if($get_user_assigned_page_url > 0)
                    {
                        $create_pageurlid_array = array();
                        if(!empty($get_user_assigned_page_url))
                        {
                            foreach($get_user_assigned_page_url as $url_id)
                            {
                                array_push($create_pageurlid_array,$url_id->pageurl_id);
                            }
                        }

                        $this->session->set_userdata('user_assigned_pageurl_id',$create_pageurlid_array);
                    }

                    $get_user_last_login_data = $this->login_model->get_user_last_login_data();
                    if(!empty($get_user_last_login_data))
                    {
                        $set_session_user_last_log_info = array(
                        'last_login_time'=>$get_user_last_login_data->login_time,
                        'last_login_date'=> $get_user_last_login_data->login_date
                        );
                    }
                    else{
                        $set_session_user_last_log_info = array(
                        'last_login_time'=> date('h:i:s'),
                        'last_login_date'=> date('Y-m-d')
                        );
                    }

                    $this->session->set_userdata($set_session_user_last_log_info);
                    $desg_name = $this->global_model->get_designation_by_id($data['login_status']->designation);
                    $work_role_name = $this->global_model->get_designation_by_work_role_id($data['login_status']->work_role);
                    $college_name = $this->global_model->get_college_by_id($data['login_status']->college_id);
                    $designation_college_name = array('desig_name'=>$desg_name->designation,'work_role_name'=>$work_role_name->designation,'college_name'=>$college_name->college_name,'collge_sams_code'=>$college_name->college_reg_no);
                    $this->session->set_userdata($designation_college_name);
                    $session_master_data_id = $this->login_model->get_session_master_data_id();
                    $fin_year_data = $this->login_model->get_finance_year();
                    //echo $this->session->userdata('college_id'); exit;
                    $college_current_fy_session_details = $this->login_model->get_college_current_cur_fy_session($this->session->userdata('college_id'));
                    //echo $college_current_fy_session_details->session_auto_id;
                    //exit;
                    $this->session->set_userdata('session_master_auto_id',$college_current_fy_session_details->session_auto_id);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('fyn_ye_sess_start_date',$college_current_fy_session_details->session_yr_from);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('fyn_ye_sess_end_date',$college_current_fy_session_details->session_yr_to);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('fyn_ye_sess_name',$college_current_fy_session_details->session_name);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('fin_yr_id',$fin_year_data->fin_yr_id);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('fin_yr_name',$fin_year_data->fin_yr_name);
                    $this->session->sess_time_to_update=0;
                    //$this->session->sess_update();
                    //logot session security audit
                    $csrf_value=md5(rand(1111,9999));
                    setcookie('csrf_cookie_value',$csrf_value,0,'/','',false,true);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('csrf_cookie_value_sess',$csrf_value);
                    redirect('welcome','location');
                    }
                    else{
                        if(!empty($get_userid_by_username))
                        {
                            $set_attemp_status = $this->login_model->set_login_attempts($get_userid_by_username->userid);
                        }

                        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', 'Login authentication failed.Invalid username or password.');
                        redirect('login-type-select','location');
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', 'Login authentication failed.Invalid Security Code.');
                    redirect('login-type-select','location');
            }
        }

    //$str = hash ( "sha256", $password );
}**
```

showing error on line:

```
$designation_college_name = array('desig_name'=>$desg_name->designation,'work_role_name'=>$work_role_name->designation,'college_name'=>$college_name->college_name,'collge_sams_code'=>$college_name->college_reg_no);
```

**

Comment: The error normally has more information than that. Please show us ALL the error message

Comment: Just try to add these conditions before this line you will get your answer
`if(!$desg_name){ echo '$desg_name is not set'; }if(!$work_role_name){ echo '$work_role_name is not set'; }if(!$college_name){ echo '$college_name is not set'; } `

Comment: Basically one of those object you load before that line did not work as you expected and one of those objects in not an object. Do a `var_dump()` on each onject being used in that line until you fnd the one that is not as you expected it to be

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/Login_controller.php

Line Number: 200

Backtrace:

File: E:\program_files\wamp3\www\capa_staging_remove_xss\application\controllers\Login_controller.php
Line: 200
Function: _error_handler

File: E:\program_files\wamp3\www\capa_staging_remove_xss\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: it shows that $college_name is not set. How to set $college_name?